# Struct API changed after upgrade kernel to 4.1.3

Tags: linux-kernel

`struct net_device` has no member named `pm_qos_req`.

Where can I find the relevant API structure?

Answer (score 1):

**SHORT ANSWER**

`pm_qos_req` field in `struct net_device` was using only for `e1000e` driver, therefore it was decided to move this field to `e1000e` driver structure, so that rest of drivers that use `struct net_device` will not waste a few bytes of memory when allocating `struct net_device`. See [e2c6544829](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=e2c6544829f8df396a0a233c86d5ee78f405ffef) commit for details.

If you are developing `e1000e` driver and having issues, you can back-port [e2c6544829](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=e2c6544829f8df396a0a233c86d5ee78f405ffef) commit to your kernel baseline.

Otherwise, if you are maintaining some driver which is not upstreamed and is using `pm_qos_req`, use [e2c6544829](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=e2c6544829f8df396a0a233c86d5ee78f405ffef) commit as reference to rework your driver. Basically you need to add `pm_qos_req` field to your driver struct and use it from that struct instead of `struct net_device`.

**THE WHOLE INVESTIGATION**

Here is how you can figure this out:

1. Download mainline kernel:

   ```
   $ git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git
   ```
2. Checkout to corresponding tag (well, in your case you can skip this step):

   ```
   $ git checkout v4.1-rc3
   ```

   (`v4.1-rc3` is a tag; all tags can be listed by `git tag` command)
3. Search for `pm_qos_req` text changed in `include/linux/netdevice.h` file, using git:

   ```
   $ git log -S'pm_qos_req' --oneline -- include/linux/netdevice.h
   ```

   It will give you next commits:

   ```
   01d460d   net: Remove remaining remnants of pm_qos from netdevice.h
   e2c6544   e1000e: Move pm_qos_req to e1000e adapter
   536721b   net: kernel-doc compliant documentation for net_device
   ed77134   PM QOS update
   ```

   Top commit in that list is the last one (was added most recently).
4. Check out interested commits with `git show` command. You are particularly interested in `e2c6544` commit (it's where `.pm_qos_req` was removed from `struct net_device`):

   ```
   $ git show e2c6544
   ```

   Pay attention to commit message:

   ```
   e1000e is the only driver requiring pm_qos_req, instead of causing
   every device to waste up to 240 bytes. Allocate it for the specific
   driver.
   ```
5. Now we can checkout to previous kernel versions and check which drivers are using this `pm_qos_req` field.

   ```
   $ git grep -n '\bpm_qos_req\b' v3.0 -- drivers/
   ```

   From `grep` output we can see that only `e1000e` driver is using this field.

Comment: Hmm… Any reason why `grep` instead of `git grep` which is much more efficient? (Especially usage of like `git grep -n pm_qos_req v3.0 -- include/linux/`)

Comment: @AndyShevchenko Wow, nice catch! Didn't think about `git grep`.

Comment: No need to checkout as well :-)